# Export data from selected cells into txt format

Tags: excel, vba, text, export

I have data in a cell which has an equation linked to another cell.

After exporting it is unable to find the values so it is writing # Ref in said text file.

Also it is writing  ";" (semicolons for the commas).

```vb
Sub ExportRangetoFile()
'Update 20130913
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim saveFile As String
Dim WorkRng As Range
On Error Resume Next
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add
WorkRng.Copy
wb.Worksheets(1).Paste
saveFile = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(fileFilter:="Text Files (*.txt), *.txt")
wb.SaveAs Filename:=saveFile, FileFormat:=xlText, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Copy/Paste use either PasteSpecial, Values OR just assign the value of the target range to the value of the source range. That way you won't paste the formulas across to the new WorkBook and won't get #Ref

Edit: The 2nd half of your question - try using one of the correct file formats (xlText isn't) for saving comma separated files - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple VBA Sub that deals with the OP requirement to use the text displayed not the formula in the cell.

The important point to note is that the property of the `Cell` is `.Text` not `.Value`

```
Sub sbMakeTXT()
 Dim iRows, iColumns, iRow, iColumn As Long
 Dim sText As String
 Dim sFileName As String
 Dim sTXTLine As String
 Dim sTab As String
 Dim iFileNumber As String
 Dim rSelectedRange As Range
 Set rSelectedRange = Application.Selection
 iColumns = rSelectedRange.Columns.Count
 iRows = rSelectedRange.Rows.Count
 sTab = Chr(9)
 sTXTLine = ""
 sFileName = "C:\Users\david\Desktop\a.txt"
 iFileNumber = FreeFile
 Open sFileName For Output As iFileNumber
 For iRow = 1 To iRows
  For iColumn = 1 To iColumns
   ' Use the .Text in the Cell not .Value to deal with formula results
   sText = Cells(iRow, iColumn).Text
   ' Remove TABs in case they interfere with the file structure
   sText = Replace(sText, sTab, "")
   sTXTLine = sTXTLine & sTab & sText
  Next iColumn
  Print #iFileNumber, sTXTLine
  sTXTLine = ""
 Next iRow
 Close #iFileNumber
End Sub
```

Use the following data as test data -

| ShipperID | CompanyName | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Speedy Express | (503) 555-9831 |
| 2 | United Package | (503) 555-3199 |
| 3 | Federal Shipping | (503) 555-9931 |